# How to change font size using i3-wm?

Tags: fonts, i3-wm

When I start ubuntu with i3-wm the font of all Applications is too big.
How do I change the Font and Size?

I already looked into i3 Documentation but found nothing about this topic.

Comment: in unity you can set something that will make all apps (chrome, rhythmbox, etc) smaller, i think that's what this question is about. if so, i'm aslo interested in the answer (which is *not* the link to the font stuff from i3 doc)

Answer (score 27):

You need to change the configuration of i3, copying `/etc/i3/config` file to `~/.config/i3/config` and then editing/adding your font configuration:

```
cp /etc/i3/config ~/.config/i3/config
```

Now you need to edit the file and add your preferences using the following syntax:

```
font <X core font description>
font pango:[family list] [style options] [size]
```

The first line describes the font description using the X core format, the second line describes it as space separated variables in the following order: font family  (Arial, Mono, Sans, etc.); style options such Bold, Italic, Underscore, etc.; and the last the **size**. [Pango](http://www.pango.org/) is the layout engine used.

You can look at all the entries and modify what you like, example:

```
font -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-C-70-iso10646-1
font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 10
font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono, Terminus Bold Semi-Condensed 11
font pango:Terminus 11px
```

Source:

- http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#fonts

Answer (score 9):

Gtk programs will use gtk settings. If all fonts everywhere are too small you can work around it by changing display settings, e.g., what I do with my htpc and telly is to set dpi value. Setting them via gnome control center or whatever should work if you start gnome-settings-daemon in ~/.i3/config, otherwise, settings are in like ~/.gtkrc-2.0 and ~/.config/gtk-3.0.

Comment: this and only this worked for me